# Android force Horizontal (landscape) layout

Tags: android, layout

I'm pretty close to finished with my first game for Android, and I've come across a problem that's so simple I'm sure I'll feel stupid for not knowing how to solve it, but how can I force the app to stay in a Horizontal layout?  Right now, if you turn the phone (emulator) it flips the graphics and squeezes them.  I want the game to start horizontally and stay that way regardless of how the user turns the phone.

Thank you.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Open the AndroidManifest.xml and add the following android:screenOrientation="landscape"
e.g.

```
 <activity android:name=".ActivtyName" 
       android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                >
```

Answer (score 15):

To do this at the Activity level, in case you want to change it dynamically or allow the user to select the orientation, use setRequestedOrientation in your Activity's onCreate method.

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

etc...

Comment: setRequestedOrientation() is not visible for me on the view/layout. so can you tell me how to get it.

Comment: This actually worked for me, the android:screenOrientation="landscape" did not.

Answer (score 6):

In the AndroidManifest file, try add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` to the activity's attribute.

e.g.

```
<activity android:name=".myMainActivity"
          android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Or, you could use a `R.styleable` file and set the Orientation settings there. [More info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity%5FscreenOrientation)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to set

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

on your Activity in the manifest.  It doesn't look like there's an Application wide setting, so you'll probably need to do it for each Activity separately.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier way might help someone having same problem and dont want to deal with xml. You can go to Application Nodes select your activity and select screen orientation. See the image attached for clarity.[image]