# Force orientation depending on the View inside ViewFlipper

Tags: android, orientation, viewflipper

I have a ViewFlipper with several ScrollViews inside. Depending on the child ScrollView I need to force the ViewFlipper's orientation to portrait or landscape. How can I achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: i m not sure but i think that at runtime you can't change the orientation through code,it is done by device sensor at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

In the first document, note that you can provide different layout files for landscape versus portrait modes.  For example, for landscape mode, you could have a layout file in res/layout-land.

If you want more help putting the pieces together, just ask.

---

**Edit:** It looks like I misread the original question.  Take a look at these two posts:

1. [Force an Android activity to always use landscape mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150287/force-an-android-activity-to-always-use-landscape-mode)
2. [Android force Horizontal (landscape) layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067426/android-force-horizontal-layout)