# Setting landscape mode only to Android Google Map Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, supportmapfragment

I have a MapFragment class, which will take up the full screen upon calling it.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067426/android-force-horizontal-layout), I understand that forcing a horizontal layout will require changes in the Android Manifest. However, how can I achieve this if it's for a MapFragment class?

This is my xml for my map display, if it helps:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_map"
    android:name=".com.fragments.MapFragment"
    class="com.fragments.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="tag_fragment_map" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend the `MapFragment` class. When `onAttach()` is invoked store the current orientation of an activity ( by calling `getActivity().getRequestedOrientation()` ) to an integer then set the parent's orientation to landscape. This is temporary. If your `MapFragment` is no longer used it will set the parent's old orientation.

```
public class DummyMapFragment extends MapFragment
{

    private int activityOrientation;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity arg0) {

        super.onAttach(arg0);

        activityOrientation = arg0.getRequestedOrientation();

                 arg0.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        Activity parent = getActivity();

        if(parent != null)
                    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(activityOrientation);

        super.onStop();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Seems to have helped to solve my problem! =)

Comment: Hi sorry, I just realized that once i do a .replace() to change the mapfragment to another fragment, the landscape position remains... is there a way to change it back to normal?

Comment: Can you try onStop() instead of onDestroy() ??

Comment: It sort of works now, but problem is when i got to the 2nd page and when i pressed the back button, the map is in protrait mode again, and the header which I removed in the beginning becomes visible again

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
getActivity().setRequestedScreenOrientation(SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
```

Also check this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251930/allow-rotation-landscape-in-one-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

define activity in manifest file like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".yourMapActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_profile"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
```

Comment: Fragment always attached within the activity. i suppose you have activity where your FrameLayout is attached with and with in which DummyMapFragment should be attached.

Comment: But I only want my mapfragment to be landscape. i don't want my other fragments to be landscape once i replace it.

Comment: Then You should check which which fragment is being displayed. and if it is MapFragment den programatically set screen orientation to landscape.